# How to reference an AppDelegate instance variable from the custom controller action?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I want to be able (as a learning exercise for controllers) have a button on the initial view I setup, then if you click the button an action occurs which swaps out the view from view 1 to view 2.  I'm not sure how you this?  See the section in the code below where I would like to put in the code that does this.

Can any post the code I would need?  (i.e. which would cover how to reference a variable I established in the AppDelegate).  Let me know if this practice exercise I've given myself is flawed somewhere.  Thanks.

AppDelegate *.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class gregsController;
@class Gregs2ndController;  

@interface windowsBasedAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    gregsController *viewController;
    Gregs2ndController *view2Controller;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet gregsController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Gregs2ndController *view2Controller;

@end
```

AppDelegate *.m

```
#import "windowsBasedAppDelegate.h"
#import "gregsController.h"
#import "Gregs2ndController.h"

@implementation windowsBasedAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize view2Controller;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSLog(@"windowsBasedAppDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");

    //[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window addSubview:view2Controller.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Custom Controller *.m

```
#import "gregsController.h"
@implementation gregsController
- (IBAction)logSomething {
    NSLog(@"About to switch views");
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

        // *** HOW DO I REFERENCE view2Controller AND PUT THIS AS THE VIEW  ???? ****

    NSLog(@"Finished switching views");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reference to your app delegate is available anywhere you want it via the [UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) singleton:

```
#import "gregsController.h"
@implementation gregsController
- (IBAction)logSomething {
    NSLog(@"About to switch views");
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    // *** HOW DO I REFERENCE view2Controller AND PUT THIS AS THE VIEW  ???? ****
    // Like this:
    windowsBasedAppDelegate* appDelegate = (windowsBasedAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:appDelegate.view2Controller.view];

    NSLog(@"Finished switching views");
}
```

Comment: `appDelegate.view2Controller` must be changed to  `appDelegate.view2Controller.view`

Comment: got this actually - "accessing unknown 'view' component of a property" against your last line [i.e. appDelegate.window...]

Comment: PS..Could this because view2Controller wasn't instantiated?  I didn't explicitly instantiate either viewController or view2Controller, however perhaps as the former was automatically created via Interface Builder & the linkages there?   If this is the case then the question is I guess whether I need to instantiate (a) manually in the code or (b) is there something in IB I could do to take care of this?

Comment: You'll have to #import the header for Gregs2ndController.

Answer (score 1):

to get a reference of variable created in app delegate

testAppDelegate *appDelegate = (testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

to refer any variable from app delegate, for example you can use

appDelegate .view2Controller

Comment: can anyone please let me know why it was downvoted, so that i can correct myself.Please add comment why the ans is being downvoted

Comment: Just a theory, but when I saw this answer, all that was visible was a single line of (very random looking) code.

Comment: I think you could have edited or added a comment.was it worth downvoting :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can access your app delegate and change view like this:

```
#import "windowsBasedAppDelegate.h"

windowsBasedAppDelegate *delegate = (windowsBasedAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
view2Controller *view_controller = delegate.view2Controller;

[window addSubView:view_controller.view];
[window becomeKeyWindow];
```

Comment: actually got (a) 'view2Controller' undeclared, and (b) 'window' undeclared with this...having a look into it now